# Location access isn't being asked on some browsers or security settings so my web app gets stuck loading

Tags: javascript, security, location

I have created a portfolio web app in mainly Javascript which asks for (but dosen't require) location access.

It works fine for me and my tutor signed it off, however someone has said it didn't work for them on safari. I believe their security settings are preventing the access to location question from popping up and it therefore leaves them on the loading screen which is a simple bootstrap spinner.

If location access is blocked the website still works just slightly differently, but it seems that because the location access question isn't being asked on his computer it's getting stuck.

I think basically location access isn't granted or denied and I haven't allowed for this scenario in the code so it's getting stuck.

My question is how to best approach this?

i'm currently using:

if (!navigator.geolocation)

to determine whether location access has been granted or not, ideally there would be an 'or' that I could add to this line e.g:

if (!navigator.geolocation || navigator.geolocation == unknown)

but I'm not sure what would be the correct syntax/keyword for 'unknown' would be?

Hope someone could help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to enclose the geolocation check and run the code that depends on it in an if block with a return, so it exists the function. Run the code that doesn't depend on it outside the block. If the browser doesn't ask or explicitly denies permission, the code should run with no issues.
This is an example

```
function useGeolocation() {
let div = document.getElementById("Result");
  if (Navigator.geolocation) {
    div.innerHTML = 'We got geolocation';
    //run code that uses geolocation.
    return; //We did our work so exit.
  }
  //gelocation failed, fall back to non-geolocation dependent code.
  div.innerHTML='Executing non geolocation code';
}

useGeolocation();
```